# Check once per user session - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

I would like to make a call to the underlying backend just one time when user first initiates a user session. While the session is up, the same call shall never be made again. Do I just create a singleton tied to the particular session or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place the method call in the global.asax Session_Start event.

List of available events is listed [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=126).

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the <strike>Begin_Session</strike> `Session_Start` method in the global.asax. This will fire only once and only at the beginning of the session. It will fire before any authentication occurs, though.

**Edit:** Begin_Session? Sorry. Code bleed in my brain. I've corrected the actual function name above. The bleed was for a proprietary project I had active in my noggin when I was reading the question.